# What's wrong with this route ('Future' error)?

Tags: function, flutter, dart, routes, future

I'm new to routes, and getting the error 'The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'. What's wrong with this?

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ResultsPage();
    ),
  ),
),
```

ETA: it's now working like this, which is great:

```
GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ResultsPage()));
            },
            child: Container()
```

I'm still confused about why I can't do it like this, though

```
GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) { 
                  return ResultsPage()));}
            },
            child: Container()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onTap` accepts function, and function requires input parameter.

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ResultsPage(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: I finally got the long version:
{Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {return ResultsPage();}));},  That's a lot of parentheses and brackets!

Comment: you can use `=>` as an alternative to `return` so you can remove a pair of brackets.